# My CTE SQL Query is running for too long....How can I optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I am looking to find ways to optimize the query performance but I am not sure what my options are. I hope someone can guide me. Here is my CTE query:

```
    WITH Sales AS 

     (
        SELECT
        DISTINCT s.id,
        o.item,
        o.sku
        FROM sales s
        LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON s.id = o.id
        WHERE
        o.item LIKE 'iphone%'
        AND SUBSTRING(o.item, 1, 4) = 'iphone'
        ORDER BY s.id ASC, o.item DESC
        )

        SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT Sales.id) AS this,
        m.date,
        COUNT(DISTINCT m.z)
        FROM Sales
        LEFT JOIN master m
        ON Sales.id = m.id
        WHERE
        LOWERCASE(m.id) LIKE '%ipad%'
        AND LOWERCASE(Sales.id) NOT LIKE '%pod%'
        GROUP BY m.date
        HAVING
        m.date > date_start AND m.date < date_end
        ORDER BY this ASC
        LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results and explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

set the condition

```
m.date > date_start AND m.date < date_end
```

from the having to the where clauses...

and if possible try to remove the casts LOWERCASE in columns in the where clause and set table / column to a case insensitive collation

Comment: Thank you! Do you see any benefit of using a sub-query instead? Will that make any difference?

Comment: @cocoo84hh a subquery would be equivalent to your cte..

but probably you should rewrite the query with joins without cte / subquery...

if you can build a fiddle with some data, I can try to help you to refactoring the query

Comment: that is amazing. Let me work on it tomorrow and share. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: can you start a private chat with me? I wanted to continue with this query and how I can optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING(o.item, 1, 4) = 'iphone'
```

will always fail.  Maybe you meant 6?

```
    WHERE  LOWERCASE(m.id) LIKE '%ipad%'
      AND  LOWERCASE(Sales.id) NOT LIKE '%pod%'
```

Suggest you learn about `FULLTEXT` indexing and use

```
   WHERE MATCH(m.id) AGAINST("+ipad" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is `id` really a string like that?  (Convention is for `id` to be a unique number defining the row.)

```
    HAVING  m.date > date_start
       AND  m.date < date_end
```

Seems like that should be in the `WHERE` clause.  At that point `LEFT` does not make sense.

```
  ON Sales.id = m.id
```

Why are you testing each one separately in the `WHERE`?  If they are the same, you could test one.

Clean up those things; then we can discuss indexes.